# Framework7 With Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, webforms, html-framework-7

I have to implement [Framework7](https://framework7.io/) with Asp.Net Framework 4.5. I had spent couple of hours but detail section is not loading. Sample Theme is: [Theme](http://sindevo.com/varius/main/) Not a single sample / tutorials found in goolge for Asp.Net with Framework7.

Please Note: I don't want to use WebApi until last hope. Saying that, for security reasons, do not send/receive data using WebApi, but I want to load data using Page_Load event and submit data using Asp.Net button C# button click event.

Master Page :   - All code is in Master File as per above theme from index.html.

Default.aspx :

```html
<div class="pages"> </div>
```

Please anyone can guide me how can I resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

[Update] :

Add Client Side Library : Any version >= 5.0.0. All version using libman.json

```js
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "defaultProvider": "cdnjs",
  "libraries": [
    {
      "library": "framework7@5.6.0",
      "destination": "lib/framework7/"
    }
  ]
}
```

All Version after 5.0.0,  generates random error like

**Version : From 5.0.0 to 5.5.0**

libman.json : error LIB010: Failed to download resource from "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/framework7/**[Version]**/framework7-lite.esm.bundle.d.ts"

**Version : From 5.5.1 to 5.6.0**

libman.json : error LIB010: Failed to download resource from "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/framework7/**[Version]**/framework7.bundle.less"

**Thus my question is: Should Framework7 is compatible with Asp.net 4.5 Framework.**

Comment: _"for security reasons, do not send/receive data using WebApi, but I want to load data using Page_Load event and submit data using Asp.Net button C# button click event."_ ...sorry but this doesn't really make a lot of sense. There is no difference in security between these two situations (as long as it's properly implemented). Both are sending and receiving data between the browser and the server, using HTTP. If you use HTTPS and ensure all requests are authenticated and authorised, then there should be no difference in the risk between these two scenarios.

Comment: But if you're going to use a client-side HTML framework to render your UI, it would definitely make more sense to use Web API as the backend, because with ASP.NET Webforms you have a competing, server-rendered UI framework which is going to be confusing and/or cause problems, as you've discovered. It can probably be made to work, but it will be awkward. So I think you should go with the Web API backend. I don't really understand why you think it could cause a problem - can you be clearer about what exactly you think the risk is?

Comment: P.S. the other reason you'd want to use web api for your backend is that, as far as I understand it, Framework7 is really only aimed at creating UIs for mobile devices. Therefore if you want a regular web UI or a desktop UI to go with it, you'll find that much easier to do if you've already got an API done which it can use to communicate with and send/receive data. So that can save you quite a lot of work.

Comment: yes, its true. I have to upgrade current code. so can't change each and everything until its required.

Comment: Is the current ASP.NET code a mobile-enabled application already? If not, then you can't really just add framework7 code into it, otherwise you'll destroy the existing functionality I think. Unless you have a whole set of separate pages aimed at mobile users, but it will be trickier to ensure each type of device gets to the correct area of the site. I suggest building an API initially just for the functions your mobile app requires (it might be less than the full version?). Some of the data-layer code can probably be pasted from your old app, just change how it returns the data (as JSON now).

Comment: Then eventually you can refactor the old app to use the API as well.

Comment: current ASP.NET code a mobile-enabled application already using app.version = '1.4.0';

Comment: I want to upgrade with 5.6.0 (latest version)

Comment: ok your update gives us a more specific problem, and more details, that's great. As far as I can see the error has nothing to do with asp.net. It's simply failing to download some files. Maybe the URLs are wrong. Have you checked?

Comment: Yes, GitHub Code works fine with html pages.

Comment: I had checked with most of version starts from 5.0.0. but no luck. looking for someone expert advice.

Comment: ok well I know a lot about asp.net, but not framework7. However your question has been tagged with that product so hopefully someone with more knowledge of that will come forward.